# Minecraft: Items scrolling though inventory

Tags: java, minecraft

I am making kind of like a CS:GO Cases plugin for a Minecraft and if you don't know what CS:GO cases are here is an explanation: So you will do a command(/common) and then it opens a common case; there is also going to be rare and legendary. But when you execute the command, a inventory should open and items should start spinning and then slow down and eventually stop and the item in the middle is the item you win I have created a inventory I just have to figure out how to make the items spin. I tried to do:

```
for(int x = 0; 0 < 18; x++)`
{
   inv.setItem(x, diamondSword);
   inv.setItem(x, diamondShovel);
   inv.setItem(x, Chest);
   inv.setItem(x, Compass);
   inv.setItem(x, stick);
   inv.setItem(x, stonePickaxe);
   inv.setItem(x, diamond);
   inv.setItem(x, emerald);
}
```

And what happens is that the inventory opens and it is full of emeralds (The last item).
So I tested and printed x in the server chat and when I do the command it makes all of the numbers appear instantly like:
1
2
3
4
5
... until it hits 17.

So I just want a little explanation on how I could make the items cycle through the GUI that appears when executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay with a scheduler. runTaskTimer runs a set of functions forever with a delay between run. Last argument is amount of time inbetween in ticks. 20 ticks = 1 second
Example code:

```
List<ItemStack> list = {item1, item2, item3, item4};
int x = 0;
plugin.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new Runnable()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    inv.setItem(slot, list.get(x);
    x++
  }
}, 40);
```